# Ns3 programming Video trace

Tags: ns-3

I'm new to programming with ns3 and I would like to ask how can I use a video trace file (obtained from http:/trace.eas.asu.edu) with a simple network topology (like the one described in first.cc in tutorials). I've already download the trace file and put the file into the ns3-22 file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ns3::UdpTraceClient to load a trace file and send it.
You have to make sure that the file is formated in the proper way as described below:

- Trace files could be downloaded form : http://www2.tkn.tu-berlin.de/research/trace/ltvt.html
- (the 2 first lines of the file should be removed)
- A valid trace file is a file with 4 columns:
- -1- the first one represents the frame index
- -2- the second one indicates the type of the frame: I, P or B
- -3- the third one indicates the time on which the frame was generated by the encoder
- -4- the fourth one indicates the frame size in byte

You can also try the Evalvid patch. It is a bit outdated and might require some effort to port.